# How to get all title values in an object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, key, key-value

How to get all title values from the data object.

```
const data = [
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 1,
    "title": "sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit",
    "body": "quia et suscipit\nsuscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum\nreprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam\nnostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto"
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 2,
    "title": "qui est esse",
    "body": "est rerum tempore vitae\nsequi sint nihil reprehenderit dolor beatae ea dolores neque\nfugiat blanditiis voluptate porro vel nihil molestiae ut reiciendis\nqui aperiam non debitis possimus qui neque nisi nulla"
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 3,
    "title": "ea molestias quasi exercitationem repellat qui ipsa sit aut",
    "body": "et iusto sed quo iure\nvoluptatem occaecati omnis eligendi aut ad\nvoluptatem doloribus vel accusantium quis pariatur\nmolestiae porro eius odio et labore et velit aut"
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 4,
    "title": "eum et est occaecati",
    "body": "ullam et saepe reiciendis voluptatem adipisci\nsit amet autem assumenda provident rerum culpa\nquis hic commodi nesciunt rem tenetur doloremque ipsam iure\nquis sunt voluptatem rerum illo velit"
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 5,
    "title": "nesciunt quas odio",
    "body": "repudiandae veniam quaerat sunt sed\nalias aut fugiat sit autem sed est\nvoluptatem omnis possimus esse voluptatibus quis\nest aut tenetur dolor neque"
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 6,
    "title": "dolorem eum magni eos aperiam quia",
    "body": "ut aspernatur corporis harum nihil quis provident sequi\nmollitia nobis aliquid molestiae\nperspiciatis et ea nemo ab reprehenderit accusantium quas\nvoluptate dolores velit et doloremque molestiae"
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 7,
    "title": "magnam facilis autem",
    "body": "dolore placeat quibusdam ea quo vitae\nmagni quis enim qui quis quo nemo aut saepe\nquidem repellat excepturi ut quia\nsunt ut sequi eos ea sed quas"
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 8,
    "title": "dolorem dolore est ipsam",
    "body": "dignissimos aperiam dolorem qui eum\nfacilis quibusdam animi sint suscipit qui sint possimus cum\nquaerat magni maiores excepturi\nipsam ut commodi dolor voluptatum modi aut vitae"
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 9,
    "title": "nesciunt iure omnis dolorem tempora et accusantium",
    "body": "consectetur animi nesciunt iure dolore\nenim quia ad\nveniam autem ut quam aut nobis\net est aut quod aut provident voluptas autem voluptas"
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 10,
    "title": "optio molestias id quia eum",
    "body": "quo et expedita modi cum officia vel magni\ndoloribus qui repudiandae\nvero nisi sit\nquos veniam quod sed accusamus veritatis error"
  },
  {
    "userId": 2,
    "id": 11,
    "title": "et ea vero quia laudantium autem",
    "body": "delectus reiciendis molestiae occaecati non minima eveniet qui voluptatibus\naccusamus in eum beatae sit\nvel qui neque voluptates ut commodi qui incidunt\nut animi commodi"
  },
  {
    "userId": 2,
    "id": 12,
    "title": "in quibusdam tempore odit est dolorem",
    "body": "itaque id aut magnam\npraesentium quia et ea odit et ea voluptas et\nsapiente quia nihil amet occaecati quia id voluptatem\nincidunt ea est distinctio odio"
  },
  {
    "userId": 2,
    "id": 13,
    "title": "dolorum ut in voluptas mollitia et saepe quo animi",
    "body": "aut dicta possimus sint mollitia voluptas commodi quo doloremque\niste corrupti reiciendis voluptatem eius rerum\nsit cumque quod eligendi laborum minima\nperferendis recusandae assumenda consectetur porro architecto ipsum ipsam"
  },
  {
    "userId": 2,
    "id": 14,
    "title": "voluptatem eligendi optio",
    "body": "fuga et accusamus dolorum perferendis illo voluptas\nnon doloremque neque facere\nad qui dolorum molestiae beatae\nsed aut voluptas totam sit illum"
  },
  {
    "userId": 2,
    "id": 15,
    "title": "eveniet quod temporibus",
    "body": "reprehenderit quos placeat\nvelit minima officia dolores impedit repudiandae molestiae nam\nvoluptas recusandae quis delectus\nofficiis harum fugiat vitae"
  },
  {
    "userId": 2,
    "id": 16,
    "title": "sint suscipit perspiciatis velit dolorum rerum ipsa laboriosam odio",
    "body": "suscipit nam nisi quo aperiam aut\nasperiores eos fugit maiores voluptatibus quia\nvoluptatem quis ullam qui in alias quia est\nconsequatur magni mollitia accusamus ea nisi voluptate dicta"
  },}
```

Comment: Please show us what you have tried

Comment: Research [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: You mean just the 4 titles that repeat or every of them?

Comment: `How to get`,  that part is a little broad, what is get?, the `data` object already has the titles, there is nothing to get.  You can use `Array.map` to map into a different shape, but it's still going to be an array.  Often questions like this is really help if you show an expected output, and like pointed out, showing what you tried will also help, especially with avoiding downvotes.

Answer (score -2):

Try:

```js
data.map(i => i.title)
```

Comment: Yes. I try this one